# pd.HDFStore : Missing optional dependency 'pytables'

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdf

I am encoutering the error "ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'pytables'.  Use pip or conda to install pytables" when runing the following code

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.HDFStore(data + ".h5")
```

Im using conda, on windows 10 with python 3.8.13

I tried the following command line in an admin shell but none are working :

```
- pip uninstall tables
pip install tables==3.6.1

- conda install -c conda-forge pytables

- conda install pytables

- conda install snappy
```

I also check that hdf4 /hdf5 and hdf5py were installed

Comment: I had the same problem, but for me a `pip install --upgrade pip` followed by `pip install tables` fixed the issue. Are you sure that you installed in the correct environment and/or that you interpreter has access to installed package? Do you have any problem if you try to install/import other packages?